# JavaScript: how to access the prototype of a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype-programming

Maybe silly question to the JS gurus and ninjas out there but here goes:

My understanding of the prototype object/property of an object is that it is a blueprint for future instances of an object. Given this, shouldn't a newly created instance of an object be identical to the constructor object that created it?

```
var x = new Object(); 
console.log(x === Object.prototype); // returns false. why??
```

*** UPDATE ***

So understanding that this will return false because they are referencing different things, I still find that new Object() and `Object.prototype` contain a different number of properties. So to refine my question:  How do I correctly check the number of properties in a prototype Object; how do I iterate through them?

The reason I got confused by this is that if I create a simple constructor function:

```
function Circle(){
   this.tail = "yes, has tail";
}
```

and want to get the number of properties it has, doing something like:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Circle.prototype)); 
// returns "constructor", I expected it to return "tail"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`===` does not answer the question of whether two things are equivalent, but whether they are references to the same object.

`x` and `Object.prototype` in your example may have the same properties, so you can call them equivalent, but they are two different objects.

If you do

```
x.foo = 3
```

they are now no longer equivalent, because they were two different objects.  You changed one but not the other.

If

```
x === Object.prototype
```

were true, then

```
x.foo === Object.prototype.foo
```

would be the same regardless of what you assign to `x.foo` or `Object.prototype.foo`.

EDIT:

> ```
> function Circle(){ this.tail = "yes, has tail"; }
>
> console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Circle.prototype)); 
> // returns "constructor", I expected it to return "tail"
> ```

There is no `tail` property on `Circle.prototype` because you have never done `Circle.prototype.tail = ...;`.  You define `tail` only on `Circle` **instances** via `this.tail = ...;`.

> I still find that `new Object()` and `Object.prototype` contain a different number of properties.

You are also doing [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).  The **own** properties are those that are not inherited from the prototype, so by using that function on `x` you are explicitly excluding all the properties of `Object.prototype`.

The docs for [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) explain "own property" pretty well:

> This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the `in` operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(x) === Object.prototype); // true`

If you want to get the hidden property `[[Prototype]]` that points to the next element in the prototype chain for an object just call `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

Also you mis-understand how the prototype chain works.

For any given object, if you look up a property it will first look at that object. It will then (recursively) look at the objects `[[Prototype]]` value for whether it has that property.

Example prototype chains :

```
var o = new Object();
// o -> Object.prototype -> null
var a = new Array();
// a -> Array.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
var Super = function () {};
var Child = function () {};
Child.prototype = Object.create(Super.prototype);
var c = new Child();
// c -> Child.prototype -> Super.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

x is an instance of "Object". You probably want to check if x has a Object as constructor. Prototype isn't constructor.
Try this

```
var x = new Object(); 
console.log(x.constructor === Object);
```

Comment: `.constructor` is a de-facto standard. Some people forget to use `.constructor` and such logic would break.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your update:

`this` within a constructor function is the instance created with the `new` keyword, not the `prototype`.

So, in the case of your snippet...

```
function Circle(){
   this.tail = "yes, has tail";
}
```

Setting `this.tail` is similar to:

```
var c = new Circle();
c.tail = "yes, has tail";
```

`tail` is *only* a property of the instance.

To set `tail` on the `prototype`, you must use:

```
Circle.prototype.tail = "yes, has tail";
```

Now, "Own" properties are those set directly on the instance. These counter and override `prototype` properties of the same name:

```
function Circle() {
    // give the instance its "own" `foo` property
    this.foo = 'qux';
}

Circle.prototype.foo = 'foo';
Circle.prototype.bar = 'bar';

var c = new Circle();

console.log(c.foo); // the overridden "qux", not the inherited "foo"
console.log(c.bar); // "bar", as inherited

// yet the prototype still persists to have its "own" `foo`
console.log(Circle.prototype.foo); // "foo"

// While the instance has keys for all involved properties
console.log(Object.keys(c)); // [ "foo", "bar" ]

// It also retains which are its "own"
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c)); // [ "foo" ]
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, I thought that when you create a constructor function, the prototype is the duplicate of whatever the constructor defines.